# DataGrid row cast to object with null property

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid binds to an object named Quote

```
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding QuoteList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="TimeStamp" Direction="Descending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

......

     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" x:Name="MasterAllGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            HeadersVisibility="All"  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="MasterAllGrid_SelectionChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ticker" Binding="{Binding Path=Ticker}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="tenor" Binding="{Binding Path=Tenor}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="rating" Binding="{Binding Path=Rating}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bid Amount" Binding="{Binding Path=BidAmount}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bid Price" Binding="{Binding Path=BidPrice}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Offer Price" Binding="{Binding Path=OfferPrice}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Offer Amount" Binding="{Binding Path=OfferAmount}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Direction" Binding="{Binding Path=Direction}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Action" Binding="{Binding Path=Action}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Path=TimeStamp}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sender" Binding="{Binding Path=Sender.SuojiContactWrapper.SuojiContact.FullName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I tried to cast back the selected Row back to Quote

```
Quote quote = (Quote)MasterAllGrid.SelectedItem;
```

However, seems because of Sender I have to use nested property,

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Sender" Binding="{Binding Path=Sender.SuojiContactWrapper.SuojiContact.FullName}"/>
```

the casting has Sender property in Quote object as Null.

May I know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure I understand where the problem is. Is the Sender column not displaying data? Or is quote.sender = Null after retrieving it from SelectedItem?

Comment: quote.sender = Null after retrieving from SelectedItem